# Install openCV with CUDA toolkit 8.0

Tags: opencv, cuda

I'm trying to install Opencv 3.2.0 and Nvidia CUDA toolkit 8.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 but I can't configure them together. I get the following error when I try to make project using both:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
    Could NOT find CUDA: Found unsuitable version "8.0", but required is exact
    version "7.5" (found /usr/local/cuda)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:386 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
    /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:949 (find_package_handle_standard_args)

    /usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake:86 (find_package)
    /usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake:105 (find_host_package)
CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I have tried installing cuda toolkit 7.5 but its not compatible with ubuntu 16.04 I believe. I'm really clueless now, I hope someone can help with this. 
Thanks

Comment: for questions like these, I think it's customary to at least include your `CMakeLists.txt` file in your question.  You can edit your own question, click on the edit link below the tags.

Answer (score 1):

so I solved this issue by managing to install toolkit 7.5. Here is how I did it:

1. Updated nvidia driver for my Operating System
2. Download cuda toolkit 7.5 and extract it to a folder

   ```
   $ mkdir ~/Downloads/NVIDIA_TOOLKIT
   $ cd ~/Downloads
   $ ./cuda_7.5.18_linux.run -extract=~/Downloads/NVIDIA_TOOLKIT;
   ```
3. go to the virtual console by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1 and turn off
   lightdm service

   ```
   $ sudo service lightdm stop
   ```
4. cd to downloads and install the extracted toolkit and samples

   ```
   $ cd ~/Downloads/NVIDIA_TOOLKIT
   $ sudo ./cuda-linux64-rel-6.0.37-18176142.run
   $ sudo ./cuda-samples-linux-6.0.37-18176142.run
   ```
5. Set environment variables in .bashrc file

   ```
   $ PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin
   $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64
   ```
6. Turn back on the lightdm service

   ```
   $ sudo service lightdm start
   ```
7. Reboot and you should be able to use the nvcc compiler
8. For openCV you will have to downgrade your gcc/ g++ compiler to 4.9 since it is not yet compatible with the higher versions